# Should i new database model in business layer or data access layer

Tags: java, c#, hibernate, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created an dotnet core project with EF framework core, i have some question regards how to structure the code. My project has 3 layer structures, controller, business layer, data access layer. And i defined a Model called "Data" which need to save to a database. The data model  contains 5 fields which can be get form external api call. so i am wondering the following two approaches, which one is better.

Approach 1: Making 3 api calls to get the value, then create a data object and pass to data access layer, then save to database.

```
business layer:
    Data newData = new Data() {
    field1 = apiCall1
    field2 = apiCall2
    field3 = apiCall3
    }

_db.saveValue(Data newData){
}

data access layer:
    saveValue(Data newData) {
        context.save(newData)
    }
```

Approach 2: Making 3 api calls to get the value, pass the 3 api call results to data access layer, then create a data object and save to database

```
business layer:
    _db.saveValue(Model1 apiCall1, Model2 apiCall2, Mole3 apiCall3){
}

data access layer:
    saveValue(Model1 apiCall1, Model2 apiCall2, Mole3 apiCall3) {
        Data newData = new Data() {
    field1 = apiCall1
    field2 = apiCall2
    field3 = apiCall3
    }
    
    context.save(newData)
    }
```

Comment: Where does Java come into this?

Comment: i thought this will be a same concept can be apply to another language as well

Comment: That's true, but you're only supposed to add tags that are relevant to your specific question. This appears to be a C#/EF question.

Comment: also ```data access layer``` as the name states it handles the communication with the database ...i would also reconsider your naming choices of your classes like ```Data``` ...

Answer (score 1):

The best approach will be to send it using an object like you mentioned in Approach 1. However, as a part of standard process it will be recommended to use DTO(data transfer object) and automapper. Please refer to the following link to get an idea -

[using DTO and automapper in .NET Core](https://gavilan.blog/2019/03/18/asp-net-core-2-2-data-transfer-objects-dtos-and-automapper/)